# Xsl 1.0 to xsl 3.0 conversion issue

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xslt-grouping

```
xsl 1.0 version :

    <xsl:element name="CategoryCodes">
            <xsl:copy-of select="attribute::*" />
            <xsl:for-each select="GuestRoomInfo">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@Code=3">
                        <xsl:call-template name="HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@Code=5">
                        <xsl:call-template name="HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@Code=6">
                        <xsl:call-template name="HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@Code=10">
                        <xsl:call-template name="HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@Code=12">
                        <xsl:call-template name="HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@Code=13">
                        <xsl:call-template name="HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@Code=19">
                        <xsl:call-template name="HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@Code=24">
                        <xsl:call-template name="HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@Code=26">
                        <xsl:call-template name="HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@Code=28">
                        <xsl:call-template name="HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@Code=47">
                        <xsl:call-template name="HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo" />
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
            
Tried to convert into xsl 3.0 as mention below:

    <xsl:template match="CategoryCodes" name="CategoryCodes">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
        <xsl:element name="CategoryCodes">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="GuestRoomInfo" mode="HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo">
                <xsl:with-param name="selectedCodes" select="(3, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 19, 24, 26, 28, 47)" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

Expecting the compatible xsl 3.0 version xslt from xsl 1.0. So tried to do indexing with the available feature of select functionality but didn't work.

Please help in providing the optimistic approach for this in xslt 3.0 version.

Comment: Sorry your question does not make any sense. You have it tagged as xslt-grouping, but there’s no grouping done in either code example. It looks like you tried to turn a named template into a mode, but you don’t show the code for either one. You’re going to have to give us a minimal but complete example that we can run ourselves. We’ll also need an example of the output you’re trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Whether XSLT 1 or 2 or 3, you could simplify the `for-each` with all the nested `xsl:choose/xsl:when` which all seem to call the same named template into a simple `apply-templates` with a predicate and some `or` conditions listing all possible values of `@Code` (I haven't spelled them all out)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="GuestRoomInfo[@Code=3 or @Code=5 or .. or @Code=47]"/>
```

which for XSLT 2 or 3 you could simplify to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="GuestRoomInfo[@Code = (3, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 19, 24, 26, 28, 47)]"/>
```

Then your template named `HotelInfo_CategoryCodes_GuestRoomInfo` needs a `match="GuestRoomInfo"` and that seems about it; of course using a mode might make sense or be necessary if you have other places where you process `GuestRoomInfo` by matching.

For more concrete suggestions I agree with the comment, show us minimal but complete samples of the XML input, the XSLT code and the wanted result.